# how to create custom layout behaviour for recyclerview inside CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout

I am making a parallax effect using CoordinatorLayout while the recycler view starts scrolls the AppBarLayout is hiding. till this I have done. I am pasting the code below.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_sm"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimen_sm"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/dimen_sm"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/top_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_sm"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_sm"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_xs"
        app:layout_behavior="string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

right now the AppBarLayout starts hiding when the recyclerview starts scrolling. what I need is

1- is it possible to set custom behaviour for scrolling effect ? , I mean, I want to start hiding the AppBarLayout when the user reaches the last item in RecyclerView. (suppose if there is 10 items in recycler view, the parallax effect will start when it start showing 10 th item in interface)

2 - Can I use some other layout instead of AppBarLayout ?, since I have another toolbar is available, if I am using AppBarLayout I have to use theme with NoActionBar

Answer (score 0):

You can make use for custom collapsing toolbar and overwride the on expand and collapse when required i.e on recycler scroll end

Comment: can you explain please ?

Comment: Use this custom class of appbar layout from the link below https://gist.github.com/skimarxall/863585dcd7abde8f4153

and call expand app bar or collapse appBar accordingly you require